# Callback from opening of Android notification drawer

Tags: android, notifications

Is there any way I can register one of my own activities, so it gets invoked whenever the notification drawer is opened?  I know full well how to get my activity started when the user taps on my notification, but that's not what I want.  I want my activity to run earlier -- at the moment the user pulls down the notification drawer and merely reveals my notification.

As you might imagine, I want my activity to update the notification's text (i.e. call NotificationBuilder.setContentText()).

It must be possible.  For example, the 3G Watchdog app does this sort of thing (it has the notification show how much bandwidth you've used this month).  I imagine this can be done if I write an app that can never die -- a daemon of sorts -- but I understand that's considered bad form in Android apps.

Comment: If you start an activity, the entire screen will be replaced by the UI of that activity. Is this really what you want to do? If not, please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: OK, maybe it's not an activity I want triggered.  Let's say I just want some process started.

Comment: You should learn about Service and BroadcastReceiver. One of these might help you accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same, but onWindowFocusChanged&onUserLeaveHint  can help you with this:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onUserLeaveHint()

When you lose the focus, it's caused by various scenarios. One of them is the showing of the notification drawer. Another is going to recent-tasks.